# Animate after scrolling to div using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to activate an animation when you scroll past the dummy text to the div container `#crossfade` by changing its state from `animation-play-state : paused;` to `animation-play-state : running;` using my weak JQuery skills.

When `#crossfade` is < 100px from topOfwindow the animation should activate, however I am failing at getting it to work.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/pc4mur9s/40/

HTML

```
<div>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text </div>


<div id="crossfade">

  <img src="http://dvqlxo2m2q99q.cloudfront.net/000_clients/192648/file/19264814294Sny2.jpg" >
  <img src="http://dvqlxo2m2q99q.cloudfront.net/000_clients/192648/file/19264814294uIB9.jpg" >
  <img src="http://dvqlxo2m2q99q.cloudfront.net/000_clients/192648/file/19264814294HQqq.jpg" >
  <img src="http://dvqlxo2m2q99q.cloudfront.net/000_clients/192648/file/19264814294JK0g.jpg" >
</div>
```

CSS

```
#crossfade > img { 
    width: 957px;
    height: 599px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 10s;
    -webkit-animation-play-state : paused;
}

#crossfade > img:nth-child(2)  {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
#crossfade > img:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}
#crossfade > img:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    15% { opacity: 1;}
    100% { opacity: 1;}
}
```

JQuery

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#crossfade').each(function(){
    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+100) {
           $("img", this).addClass("imageAnimation")[0]
            .style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have not included jQuery in your fiddle.

Secondly, this:

```
$("img", this).addClass("imageAnimation")[0].style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
```

will only change playstate of your first image, try this instead:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('#crossfade').each(function () {
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow + 100) {
            $("img", this).addClass("imageAnimation").each(function () {
                this.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pc4mur9s/41/

Comment: Wow I can't believe I forgot to turn on JQuery in the fiddle.. embarrassing. And your solution worked perfectly, exactly what I was trying to do, thanks a lot! I appreciate it.

Comment: I've realized that this method is not compatible with Internet Explorer, is there a method that would work on both Chrome and IE?

Comment: Nevermind, just added `this.style.animationPlayState = "running";` to the JQuery